# Running docker-compose for Saleor appears to be caught in a loop, thoughts?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, saleor

I'm trying to run docker-compose up following the instructions [here](https://saleor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization/docker.html) but it appears to be stuck in a loop. I was able to bring the sample site up and make a few cosmetic changes prior to the Docker installation, but trying to do it with docker-compose has generated thumbnails 230180 times (I ran it overnight). Any ideas?

> saleor-celery |
>   saleor-celery | INFO saleor.core.utils Created 6 thumbnails [PID:11:MainThread]
>   saleor-celery | [2018-09-14 20:03:54,249: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Created 6 thumbnails
>   saleor-celery | [2018-09-14 20:03:54,295: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task saleor.product.thumbnails.create_product_thumbnails[7a05b320-4656-4304-a8a1-e9fef3cb4cd8] succeeded in 1.5320279000000028s: None
>   saleor-celery | [2018-09-14 20:03:54,298: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: saleor.product.thumbnails.create_product_thumbnails[fd833000-45f5-4029-abec-e6b828ee01af]
>   saleor-celery | INFO saleor.core.utils Creating thumbnails for  230179 [PID:11:MainThread]
>   saleor-celery | [2018-09-14 20:03:54,302: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Creating thumbnails for  230179
>   saleor-celery | [2018-09-14 20:03:55,135: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: saleor.product.thumbnails.create_product_thumbnails[7de5385c-7fc3-45c6-9ad0-133442b2ad0c]
>   saleor-celery |
>   saleor-celery | INFO saleor.core.utils Created 6 thumbnails [PID:12:MainThread]
>   saleor-celery | [2018-09-14 20:03:56,049: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Created 6 thumbnails
>   saleor-celery |
>   saleor-celery | INFO saleor.core.utils Created 6 thumbnails [PID:11:MainThread]
>   saleor-celery | [2018-09-14 20:03:56,404: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Created 6 thumbnails
>   saleor-celery | [2018-09-14 20:03:56,545: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task saleor.product.thumbnails.create_product_thumbnails[96859bd2-cb9d-49d0-ac6c-0010bf3bf76d] succeeded in 2.244128099999898s: None
>   saleor-celery | INFO saleor.core.utils Creating thumbnails for  230180 [PID:11:MainThread]
>   saleor-celery | [2018-09-14 20:03:56,550: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Creating thumbnails for  230180

Windows 10

Python 3.6

Latest (stable) Saleor

Comment: have you tried running it using docker run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue filed for this bug in Saleor: https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/issues/3114

As of the time I wrote this, there is not an official fix but are multiple workarounds listed.

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of Saleor you're using?

Could you try running:

```
docker-compose up -d 
docker-compose exec web /bin/sh -c ' python3  manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py collectstatic && python3 manage.py populatedb --createsuperuser'
```

Comment: I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

> This issue should be already [resolved](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/issues/3114#issuecomment-463262110), using `--rm` has been
>   [documented](https://saleor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization/docker.html#usage).

For your case on **generating the thumbnails**, I would suggest to run [`create_thumbnails`](https://docs.getsaleor.com/en/latest/architecture/thumbnails.html#generating-products-thumbnails-manually) between the code for populate the [`Example Data`](https://docs.getsaleor.com/en/latest/gettingstarted/example-data.html) and [`docker-compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).

So the [documented code](https://saleor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization/docker.html#usage) is slightly change like below

```
$ docker-compose config
$ docker-compose build

$ docker-compose run --rm saleor python3 manage.py migrate
$ docker-compose run --rm saleor python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear
$ docker-compose run --rm saleor python3 manage.py populatedb --createsuperuser
$ docker-compose run --rm saleor python3 manage.py create_thumbnails

$ docker-compose up
```

Please note:

- the `create_thumbnails` will place the thumbnails on `app/media/__sized__`
- some thumbnails including that **background images** for *category pages*  will be made separately by `celery` at `app/media/__sized__/*backgrounds` against a *received task* from [`redis`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html).

Following is the complete task that is *[currently assigned](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/issues/1153#issue-262094691)* by using **[celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)**:

```
Step #1: [tasks]
Step #1:   . saleor.account.emails.send_account_delete_confirmation_email
Step #1:   . saleor.account.emails.send_password_reset_email
Step #1:   . saleor.account.thumbnails.create_user_avatar_thumbnails
Step #1:   . saleor.core.analytics.ga_report
Step #1:   . saleor.core.utils.update_conversion_rates_from_openexchangerates
Step #1:   . saleor.dashboard.emails.send_promote_customer_to_staff_email
Step #1:   . saleor.dashboard.emails.send_set_password_customer_email
Step #1:   . saleor.dashboard.emails.send_set_password_staff_email
Step #1:   . saleor.order.emails.send_fulfillment_confirmation
Step #1:   . saleor.order.emails.send_fulfillment_update
Step #1:   . saleor.order.emails.send_order_confirmation
Step #1:   . saleor.order.emails.send_payment_confirmation
Step #1:   . saleor.product.tasks.update_variants_names
Step #1:   . saleor.product.thumbnails.create_category_background_image_thumbnails
Step #1:   . saleor.product.thumbnails.create_collection_background_image_thumbnails
Step #1:   . saleor.product.thumbnails.create_product_thumbnails
```

Whole process will consume a lot of memory if you miss place the sequence. You may also want to `compose up` *[the services](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)* **one after another**. I found the right sequence as below:

```
$ docker-compose up -d redis
$ docker-compose up -d celery
$ docker-compose up -d postgres

$ docker-compose up saleor
```

Combine all together

```
$ docker-compose config
$ docker-compose build

$ docker-compose run --rm saleor python3 manage.py migrate
$ docker-compose run --rm saleor python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear
$ docker-compose run --rm saleor python3 manage.py populatedb --createsuperuser
$ docker-compose run --rm saleor python3 manage.py create_thumbnails

$ docker-compose up -d redis
$ docker-compose up -d celery
$ docker-compose up -d postgres

$ docker-compose up saleor
```